# error sending email using ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I'm trying to send email to my site users (ASP.NET, VS2010), currently I'm using my gmail account for sending email, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ex = {"Failure sending mail."}
InnerException = {"The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp@gmail.com'"}
```

it is my code:

```
MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("mygmailaccount@gmail.com", "myyahooaccount@yahoo.com", "test", "test2");
            SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp@gmail.com");
            SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mygmailaccount", mygmailpassword);
            try
            {
                SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string a = ex.Message;
            }
```

what is going wrong here? should I do something in my web.config? how can I find smtp server of my own host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`smtp@gmail.com` is incorrect. You probably meant `smtp.gmail.com`. See the following question for a complete example.

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: thanks, I changed it to smtp.gmail.com and got following error:Message = "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x22sm13327733bkw.11"

Comment: Look at the answer in the link. The solution is right there. You need to enable SSL and run on port 587

Comment: yes, thanks, that was just great! but what if I'm going to send email from my own host? how can I find its port and smtp?

Comment: You will have to ask your email administrator or hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

you did not set gmail parameters correctly:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myGmailAcconut@gmail.com", "password");
```